# Force component to wait for redux state update

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux

I know that question was asked a number of times, but none of answers work for me. I got the component, which job is to display user data from react-redux BUT userData can be stored in localStorage and on first load of website this localStorage is fetched to redux state, so I get the error where I want to display initials of currently logged in user. After adding async/await to mapStateToProps function localStorage gets fetched, but I still got error saying 'Cannot get 0 of undefined', using useEffect with pre set initials also gives an error. Here is my current code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { ReactComponent as Person } from 'assets/person.svg'
import { ReactComponent as Add } from 'assets/add.svg'
import { ReactComponent as Settings } from 'assets/settings.svg'

import { Styled, Container, Button } from './styles'

const UserInfo = ({ initial }) => {
    let initials = 'UN'
    useEffect(() => {
        initials = initial
    }, [initial])
    return (
        <Styled>
            {initials}
            <Container>
                <Button>
                    <Add />
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <Person />
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <Settings />
                </Button>
            </Container>
        </Styled>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = async ({ user }) => {
    const initial = await `${user.name[0]}${user.surname[0]}`
    return initial
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserInfo)

UserInfo.propTypes = {
    initial: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

I also tried returning `initial: initial || 'UNDEF'` but I still receive an error. Additionally, when I don't refresh the browser on VSC save, I don't get an error. How can I force my component to wait for props from react-redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it a little around, but now it works, i used useState and useEffect hooks and changed a bit mapStateToProps, that's my solution:

```
const [initials, setInitials] = useState('')
useEffect(() => {
    if(name && surname) {
        setInitials(`${name[0]}${surname[0]}`)
    }
}, [name, surname])
```

and simple mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => ({
    name: user.name,
    surname: user.surname,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can be awaited: `await '${user.name[0]}${user.surname[0]}'` which is why you're still getting an error. You shouldn't need (or want, see https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#mapstatetoprops-functions-should-be-pure-and-synchronous) to make `mapStateToProps` async. You're likely already doing the async call with an async redux action. You should either check for the presence of user name/surname and return a default state if undefined

`const initial = user.name && user.surname ? '${user.name[0]}${user.surname[0]}' : 'UNDEF';`

or add an `isUserLoaded` flag for the user state and return the default state, loading indicator, or not render that portion of UI until that flag is true.

Comment: I tried doing it like you said, but that still gave me an error '0 of undefined' , and it was because Redux store was empty on page load, so page had to wait some miliseconds. I did it by another way. I'll add it as an answer

Comment: Ok. Doing it all in mapStateToProps should also work:

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => ({
  initial: user.name && user.surname ? '${user.name[0]}${user.surname[0]}' : ''
})